# pronunciation of "e"

Tags: произношение

Please tell me how the written “e” is pronounced. I've checked various online resources and am still not sure about it. I found the following rules:

“e” is pronounced as:

ii – at begin of words, after vowels, after ь, after ъ

i – between consonant and vowel

ie – at the end of a word, after the consonant

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a proper pronounce you should know three things:

- iotizing
- softening
- reduction

*Iotizing* means that if *Е* stands at the beginning of the word, or after another vowel, or after the hard or soft sign (Ь or Ъ), then it's *iotized*, i.e. it produces two sounds: Й+Э (as in *YEllow*)

*Softening*(*Palatalization*) means that if *Е* stands after a consonant, then the consonant becomes a "soft variant"("palatalized"). (Note that *Е* gives only one sound "Э", as in *Elbow*, in this case). But if the consonant has no "soft variant"[Ш, Ж, Ц], then it doesn't change, of course.

That is `Ель -> ЙЭл'`; `ЛЕc -> Л'Эс`; `МЕль ->М'Эл'`; `ЖЕчь -> ЖЭч'`; `ШЕст -> ШЭст` etc.

And there's yet another feature — *Reduction*.

*Reduction* may be applied to an *unstressed* vowel (after proper iotizing and softening!)  to pronounce it differently, so this is a matter of dialect. Unstressed Russian "Е" usually gives "И" (this is the most standard way, called ["Иканье"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)). Although saying just "Э" is OK, too.

So "***Е**(кат**е**ринбург)*" usually yields "*Й**И**(кат'**и**р'инбурк)*". But a stressed vowel never changes, e.g.: *подъ**Е**зд* -> *пад**ЙЭ**ст*.

Comment: That's very interesting that you transcribed "Екатеринбург" with a "x" at the end. Isn't final "г" devoiced into [k]? Друг [druk]? Are you from Екатеринбург? Is it the way its inhabitants pronounce the name of that city? Or is it interference of your local dialect? I'm Ukrainian, I'd pronounce it also with a [x] when I don't think about correct Russian pronunciation, but [Wiktionary says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3) it should be [k] at the end.

Comment: @YellowSky Russian, but quite far from Ural. Lower Volga, actually. Once I was in E-burg, but not really sure how they say it: either "-к" or maybe even "-г". Though there's old and rare form "Катеринбурх". After all, things like that are unstable. I can spell both "-к" and "-х". Whether it's a kind of "Ukrainian-influenced" or "Southern Russian" dialect, I can't say.

Comment: OK, I see. It's unlikely that it's "Ukrainian-influenced", if you're from the Lower Volga, it's more likely that that's Southern Russian.

Comment: Upvote for the nice explanation. And I was also surprised with "х" in "_Екатеринбург_", it's really unusual for my ear, but I heard such pronunciation from people with Southern Russian dialect and from Ukrainian speaking people. I am from Novosibirsk, btw, here we reduce "г" to "к".

Comment: @Roman, "Х" or "к": it is a hard one to pin-point, isn't it?  (pun intended)

Comment: The -x in the city name is just plain wrong

Comment: I heard Volga Germans pronouncing _г_ Ukrainian way for some reason. Never heard that from native Volga people.

Comment: It used to be common in Tula region as well...

Comment: I live in Екатеринбург and I can definitely say that here no one says [Екатеринбурх]. Only old people maybe, but I haven't heard this pronunciation at all.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the position of the letter in the word:

In word-initial position or after a vowel (in this regard the "soft sign`ь` and "had sign" `ъ` function as vowels, which is their historic origin), it's usually pronounced `ye` as in `yes`, for example. In fact, `ye` is the alphabetical name of this letter.

`E` can also represent an alternate spelling of `ё` (`yo`): the dieresis is usually omitted, except in texts for children or foreigners. In such cases, word-initial (or after a vowel) `е` is pronounced like `yo` in `New York.` There's no way to predict this difference other than knowing the actual pronunciation of the word, e.g., `елка` is a spelling variant of `ёлка`(*Christmas tree*), thus it's pronounced `'yolkah`.

Note that the letter ё, as well as its alternate spelling е, is always stressed, so `елка` in the sense of  *Christmas tree* is pronounced as `'yolkah` with the stress on the first syllable. In some cases, the dieresis is omitted from a `ë` in the middle of a word, and you just have to guess the actual pronunciation. For instance, `четырехколесный` is a alternate spelling of `четырёхколёсный`(*four-wheeled*), so the first `yo` has secondary stress, and the second `yo` has primary stress since the second part is the root and thus this 'yo' is necessarily stressed, while the first part is only a prefix (not in the formal grammatical sense, but only an auxiliary modifier of the main root, so only it can only take a secondary stress, while the main root obeys the general rule that `yo` is always stressed.)

After a consonant, `e` is pronounced differently: it usually modifies the consonant, making it "soft", i.e. palatalized. As far as I know, there are no palatalized consonants in English, so this effect is difficult to explain. Compare `man` vs.`men`, then `место` (*place*) is pronounced as`miesto`, or, `m'esto` with the [m] as in `merry`. Note how this is consistent with the name of the letter, `ie`, so it virtually adds a "soft sign", similar to `i` to the consonant; I'd write the pronunciation of`merry` in Russian as `мери`.

After a palatalized consonant, the sound itself is pronounced with a slight trace of a smile,  as in `men` as opposed to `man`, or as in "base", in which, to my ear, "b" is palatalized, kind of "bieys", which I would write as`бейс`.  In order to avoid this palatalizing effect, the letter `э` is used instead, which is pronounced identically, but does not palatalize the preceding consonant, i.e. it doesn't insert an `i` before it.

After a "hard" (non-palatalized) consonant, `е` is pronounced identically to `э`, as in `send`/"pen", (not as in "sand", "pan"), sorry if I get the pronunciation of these words wrong, English is not my language — Russian is.

Comment: Here I tried to cover two of the "three things" mentioed by @Matt in the other answer: , 
    "iotizing" and    "softening", which I called here "palatalization".